# Sequential reaction in equilibrium

Tags: equilibrium, kinetics

> Derive an equation for the steady-state rate of the sequence of reactions $$\ce{A <=> B <=> C <=> D}$$ with $[\ce{A}]$ maintained at a fixed value and the product $\ce{D}$ removed as soon as it is formed.

---

I Tried solving this question, but it got really complicated. Therefore, I was not sure whether my method and approach to solving it were correct or not. I tried to use Steady-state approximation for **A** since it is maintained at a constant concentration as per the question and I considered the concentration of **D** = 0 all the time. Then, I considered **[A] = [Ao - *a*], [B] = [*a* - *b*], [C] = [*c*] and [D] = 0**.

Comment: You could try this. As D is removed so its back reaction does not happen, and A is 'maintained'  as fixed then the scheme could be changed to $\overset{k_0}\to A \overset{k_1,\; k_{-1}}\leftrightharpoons C\overset{k_2}\to $ where B is 'lost' in the rate constants due to its equilibrium.

Comment: Square brackets denote concentration, so $[\ce{A}]$ reads as concentration of compound $\ce{A}.$ Writing $[\ce{A_0}]$ makes no sense as it suggests concentration of another compound $\ce{A_0}.$ Initial concentration should be written as $[\ce{A}]_0.$ Similarly, $[\ce{A_0} - a]$ makes even less sense as you cannot perform math operations on *chemical compounds themselves*.

Comment: Judging by the font and colors, this appears to be a question from one of the Atkins' *Physical Chemistry* textbooks. Please add a proper reference to it, and also pay attention to the notations the book uses. They are the correct ones, yours are flawed.

Answer (score 0):

$A\xrightleftharpoons[k_{-1}]{k_1}B\xrightleftharpoons[k_{-2}]{k_2}C\xrightleftharpoons[k_{-3}]{k_3}D$

I believe the rate of the overall reaction is $\frac{d[D]}{dt}$ = $k_3[C]$ since D is removed, $k_{-3}$ won't affect the reaction. Now we can apply steady-state approximation to B and C:

Steady-state approximation for B:

$\frac{d[B]}{dt} = 0 = -k_2[B] - k_{-1}[B] + k_1[A]$

$k_2[B] + k_{-1}[B] = k_1[A]$

$[B] = \frac{k_1[A]}{k_{-1}+k_2}$  (1)

Steady-state approximation for C:

$\frac{d[C]}{dt} = 0 = -k_3[C] - k_{-2}[C] + k_2[B]$

$k_3[C] + k_{-2}[C] = k_2[B]$

$[C] = \frac{k_2[B]}{k_3+k_{-2}}$ (2)

We then can substitute (1) into (2) to get

$[C] = \frac{k_2\frac{k_1[A]}{k_{-1}+k_2}}{k_3+k_{-2}}$

$[C] = \frac{k_2k_1[A]}{(k_3+k_{-2})(k_{-1}+k_2)}$ (3)

We can substitute (3) finally into $\frac{d[D]}{dt}$ = $k_3[C]$ to get the expression for $\frac{d[D]}{dt}$:

$\frac{d[D]}{dt} = \frac{k_2k_1k_3[A]}{(k_3+k_{-2})(k_{-1}+k_2)}$

This should be the steady-state rate for the reaction.